# Walks on Directed graphs

Tags: graphs, directed-graphs

Let G = (V,E) be a directed graph, where V is a finite set of nodes, and E ⊆ V × V be the set of (directed) edges (arcs). In particular, we identify a node as the initial node, and a node as the final node. Let x and B be two non-negative integer variables. Further, we decorate each edge with one of the following four instructions:

x := x + 1;

x := x − 1;

x == 0?;

x == B?;

The result is called a decorated graph (we still use G to denote it). The semantics of a decorated graph is straightforward. It executes from the initial node with some non-negative values of B and x (satisfying 0 ≤ x ≤ B), then walks along the graph. G can walk an edge (v,v0) if all of the following conditions are satisfied:

• if the edge is decorated with instruction x := x+1, the new value of x must satisfy 0 ≤ x ≤ B.

• if the edge is decorated with instruction x := x−1, the new value of x must satisfy 0 ≤ x ≤ B.

• if the edge is decorated with instruction x == 0?, the value of x must be 0.

• if the edge is decorated with instruction x == B?, the value of x must equal the value of B.

If at a node, G has more than one edge that can be walked, then G non deterministically chooses one. If at a node G has no edge that can be walked, then G crashes (i.e., do not walk any further). It is noticed that B can not be changed during any walk. However, its initial value can be any non-negative integer. We say that a decorated graph G is terminating if there are nonnegative initial values for B and x (satisfying 0 ≤ x ≤ B) such that G can walk from an initial node to a final node. Design an algorithm that answers (yes/no) whether G is terminating or not.

Comment: Is G acyclic? That would be some simplification

Comment: Can you tell us where you  encountered this task?  Can you credit the original source, and tell us what you're studying or what topic is being covered in the textbook/class where this appears?  What approaches have you tried, and what progress have you made?

Comment: This appears to be copy-pasted from some external source, without attribution - e.g., https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/let-g-v-e-directed-graph-v-finite-set-nodes-esv-xv-set-directed-edges-arcs--particular-ide-q68334433, https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/program-two-integer-variables-universal-consider-spcial-form-two-variable-programs-let-g-v-q34824236.  [Plagiarism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).